# how to use string.join to join value from an object array?

Tags: c#, string

I have an array of object e.g:

```
MyObject[] objs;
```

and within MyObject it contains a  string property,

```
object[0].stringValue
```

If I want to join the whole array of objects by their `stringValue`, how can I do it?

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
string.Join(",",objs.Select(w=>w.stringValue))
```

Comment: Fiora, is that you?!?!

Comment: Note that pre-.Net 4.0, you need to convert it to an array like so: `string.Join(",",objs.Select(w=>w.stringValue).ToArray())`.

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean to use `string.Join` to concatenate a property from multiple MyObject objects into one single string?

Then:

```
string str = string.Join(",", objs.Select(x => x.SomeProperty));
```