# how to use string.join to join all values from an object array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have the same situation as this user [how to use string.join to join value from an object array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346194/how-to-use-string-join-to-join-value-from-an-object-array) in this question. However, I want to join all values from the object instead of only 1 value.

To recap my question:
I have an array of object e.g:

```
MyObject[] objs;
```

and within MyObject it contains 3 string property,

```
object[0].stringValue1
object[0].stringValue2
object[0].stringValue3
```

If I want to join the whole array of objects by all of their stringValues (stringValues1,2 and 3), how can I do it?

I think selector doesn’t allow me to select several elements, then how to use string.join to join **several** values from an object array?

Comment: What efforts have you made on your own behalf? Calling a single method is not complex and there are examples on the web already. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: As a clue, you're going to have to do the joining of the three property values for one object separate to the joining of those combined values for each object.

Comment: How about just string.Join(",", objs.Select(o => o.stringValue1 + o.stringValue2 + o.stringValue3))? Because anyway you need additional code to glue the stringValue1~3 together regardless if you are using reflection to avoid hardcode property name or not.

Comment: @Silver make sure to checkout my answer.  It works on any object and picks up all string properties without modification, allowing you to specify both a single delimiter (e.g. comma, underscore, etc) and an optional object delimiter (e.g. newline, semicolon, etc.).  Checkout this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hwDMGA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way to solve it is to first create an array of each object's properties (using [`.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0)), and then flatten the resulting property arrays by using [`.SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0). Both of those methods are found in the *System.Linq* namespace. The resulting `IEnumerable<string>` object's items can then be joined using `string.Join()`.

If `MyObject` is defined as

```csharp
class MyObject
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Second { get; set; }
    public string Third { get; set; }
}
```

and you define `objects` as

```csharp
List<MyObject> objects = new()
{
    new() { First = "ABC", Second = "DEF", Third = "GHI" },
    new() { First = "JKL", Second = "MNO", Third = "PQR" },
    new() { First = "STU", Second = "VWX", Third = "YZ" },
};
```

, a possible implementation is:

```csharp
var flattenedObjects = objects
    .Select(obj => new[] { obj.First, obj.Second, obj.Third })
    .SelectMany(properties => properties);
    
var objectString = string.Join("_", flattenedObjects);
```

Printing the value of `objectString` to the console gives:

> ABC_DEF_GHI_JKL_MNO_PQR_STU_VWX_YZ

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YMjbbZ).

Comment: If I want to output the content format like:
ABC_DEF_GHI \n
JKL_MNO_PQR \n
STU_VWX_YZ’ \n
May I ask how can I achieve it?

Comment: @Silver Do you mean like this? https://dotnetfiddle.net/6MrAX9

Comment: I mean
`
ABC_DEF_GHI
(next line) JKL_MNO_PQR
(next line) STU_VWX_YZ
`

Comment: @Silver But the whole thing still in one string? https://dotnetfiddle.net/wu3DnV

Comment: @Silver see example in my answer above for using newline separators between objects

Answer (score 1):

See below for example usage of the two extension methods provided in the implementation section below.  The first allows you to select the properties to include, and the second includes all string properties of the object in the source collection which I believe is the exact answer to your question.

**Example Usage**

Note, the resulting output from the two examples below are ordered differently as a result of how each implementation works, however the results are otherwise identical as a result of the first example specifying all string properties on the `MyObj` sample type

[Live Fiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hwDMGA)

```cs
// Test Object
public class MyObj
{
    public MyObj(string prop1, string prop2, string prop3)
    {
        Prop1 = prop1;
        Prop2 = prop2;
        Prop3 = prop3;
    }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

// Sample Data
var list = new List<MyObj> {
    new MyObj("A1", "B1", "C1"),
    new MyObj("A1", "B2", "C2"),
    new MyObj("A3", "B3", "C3") 
};
```

*Samples using above object and data*

```cs
// Example #1 - All properties separated by single separator
Console.WriteLine(list.Join(colSeparator: ','));
// RESULT: A1,A1,A3,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3

// Example #2 - Object property separator, and different object separator
Console.WriteLine(list.Join(colSeparator: ',', rowSeparator: '\n'));

// RESULT: A1,B1,C1
           A1,B2,C2
           A3,B3,C3
```

**Implementation**

```cs
public static class EnumerableStringJoinExtension
{
    public static string Join<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, char colSeparator, char? rowSeparator = null)
    {
        var strProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(r=>r.PropertyType == typeof(string));
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(var val in values)
                sb.Append(string.Join(colSeparator, strProperties.Select(r=> r.GetValue(val)))).Append(rowSeparator ?? colSeparator);
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a one-line, handy C# without hard-coding property name you could try this:

```
string.Join("\n", objs.Select(o => string.Join("_", o.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.GetValue(o)))));
```

This produces the following result:

```
"A_B_C\nD_E_F\nG_H_I"
```

with the object array as:

```
var objs = new MyObject[]
{
    new MyObject("A", "B", "C"),
    new MyObject("D", "E", "F"),
    new MyObject("G", "H", "I")
};
```

But please note that if your class has properties in other types then you might need a `Where()` between `GetProperties()` and the second `Select()` to exclude unwanted properties.